How to suppress the .exe file for ASP.NET Core project?
I have a Razor ASP.NET Core 8 project, and when I build for debugging, it creates a .exe file (alongside the .dll). Back in .NET Core 2.1, we only had the .dll file for ASP.NET Core projects, even on Windows machines.
How do I prevent this from happening?
On some of our development machines, the .exe file will be flagged as threat by antivirus. I tried to switch the project type to library, but then it does not start.

you could try this code <PropertyGroup>   <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>   <UseAppHost>false</UseAppHost>  </PropertyGroup> which will only help you to generate dll file. after editing .csproj file rebuild the project.
